# Why is flatten not working in tensorflow keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have tried using flatten() to flatten the 3d medical images. 1 record is represented by a nifti (.nii file) which contains 256 images, each representing a different point of capture.

I loaded that into a dataset with input shape of each image being (193, 256, 256) . I created labels and passed it to neural network. I tried flattening the input in the first layer but for some weird reason it says:

*ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_50 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value **12648448** but received input with shape (193, 65536)*

if it helps, 12648448 = 193 * 256 * 256 and 65536 = 256 * 256

I can't fathom why is this happening and i've already wasted hours trying to figure it out but nothing worked !

My code:

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(193, 256, 256)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( ( images, labels ) )   # tf.constant() does not change error
#images contains multiple image. image.shape >> (193,256,256)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(dataset, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=2)
```

it crashes and `model.fit(...)` with:

**ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_50 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 12648448 but received input with shape (193, 65536)**

i would really appreciate if someone point out the issue here

Comment: To be clear: what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to interpret the whole stack of 193 images as a single input? Or are you happy with the (193, 65526) size flattened output, but confused about why the dense layer expects a different shape?

Comment: You need to prep your dataset. `dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that you are doing is right, except the input to the `fit` function has to be batches of input.

If each of the 193 images is a separate input, the model should be constructed as:

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(256, 256)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

You need to provide the input_shape as shape of each separate input. So here, it is just (256, 256).

If the whole (193, 256, 256) tensor is a single input, you have to batch the dataset before feeding into `fit`:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( ( images, labels ) )
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)  # batch_size can be 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly the Dimension with size 193 is not the number of images but rather the channels? In that case you'd have to define the parameter of the flattening layer (`data_format='channels_first'`). Also you don't have to specify `input_shape`.